# Отсутствует опция ipv6 в Cisco Packet tracer на коммутаторе 2960-24TT, что делать?

Tags: cisco, cisco-packet-tracer, cisco-ios

также пробовал включить с помощью ipv6 unicast-routing, эффекта 0, просто нет такой опции.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если использовать "?", ipv6 там тоже нет, выдает только ip

Comment: выполните `ipv6 enable`

Comment: invalid input detected в ipv6 enable с указателем на v